# Enviar mensagem para todos os managed beans

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

Quais recursos eu poderia estar utilizando para mostrar uma notificação em uma página caso ocorra uma Exception dentro de um ServletContextListener que executa uma thread?

A ideia é avisar ao usuário que algo está fora do normal e ficar fixado até que o problema seja resolvido.

```
public class Application implements ServletContextListener {

@Inject
private RadiusServerImpl server;

@Inject
private Logger log;

public Application() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)  { 
     log.info("Parando aplicações...");
     server.stop();    
}


public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)  { 
     log.info("Iniciando aplicações...");
     try{
         server.start(true, true);
     } catch (Exception e){
         // ENVIA UMA MENSAGEM AOS MANAGED BEANS (EXIBIR EM QUALQUER PÀGINA)
     }
}

}
```

Aplicação rodando no Jboss EAP com JSF, EJB, CDI, HIBERNATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os eventos CDI pode te ajudar a resolver o teu problema como está descrito [aqui](http://javaeesquad.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/getting-notified-when-java-ee.html).